# AndEngine Location

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm looking at the example of radar city example :

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/app/cityradar/CityRadarActivity.java?r=dea4a6fe72f983821ddbc287cfb90a8562f4b433

and i have implemented the ILocationListener and have enabled the location sensor
and have also enabled the location sensor through the onResume method:

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    System.gc();

    final LocationSensorOptions locationSensorOptions = new LocationSensorOptions();
    locationSensorOptions.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    locationSensorOptions.setMinimumTriggerTime(0);
    locationSensorOptions.setMinimumTriggerDistance(0);
    this.enableLocationSensor(this, locationSensorOptions);
}
```

and then tried to get location on the location changed through the implemented method

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location plocation) {
        this.mUserLocation = plocation;
        curlng = mUserLocation.getLongitude();
        curlat = mUserLocation.getLatitude();


}
```

but i am only getting zeros and i am little bit confused on whether or not use the location sensor built in andengine or use the android native location sensor?

Answer (score 1):

It uses the Android Location Sensor.

There are few things that you should check:

- Have you set the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml?
- Check whether GPS is on in your device. Even if it's on, it might take a while to lock on.

It won't be possible to give an exact answer unless you post your Logcat output.